# Elsevier `elsart`/`elsart3p` incompatibility with `algorithmic`

Tags: algorithms, incompatibility

Stuggling with the following problem for a small while and am stumped. I'm using the the [`elsart3p.cls`](http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/elsart3p.cls) document class, but it seems not to work well with the `algorithmic` package. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{elsart3p} %also doesn't work with elsart
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\REQUIRE help?
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm}
\label{alg:test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

When compiling using `latex` or `pdflatex`, I get a single error (per `\begin{algorithmic}` for each algorithm):

```
LaTeX Error: Command \AND already defined
```

...but the output looks okay. Usually I wouldn't mind too much, but I'll be passing on sources.

Anyone got any ideas for a workaround? I have a good few algorithms, so not keen on moving to another package (plus, I was never a big fan of algorithmic2e... too many braces give me vertigo).

I know this question isn't exactly blockbuster Hollywood material, but any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `elsart3p` class internally loads the `elsart` class, and the latter defines `\AND` as `\&`; the `algorithmic` package also defines `\AND` but with a different meaning, so these two definitions collide (that's why you get the error message included in your question). One possible solution is to use the `savesym` package to rename one of the two colliding names: using `\savesymbol{AND}` before loading the `algorithmic` package, renames the `\AND` command from the `elsart` as `\origAND`, avoiding the name clash:

```
\documentclass{elsart3p}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{AND}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE solved!
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Algorithm}
\label{alg:test}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

On a side note, perhaps the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package could be of interest for you.

Comment: Adding the two sentences of "\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{AND}" indeed solves the problem. Actually, it also solves the errors of using algorithm package in the autart.cls.